# Folium Map doesn't display Marker locations from Postcodes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, folium

I was given .csv file containing location information and was tasked to retrieve the latitude / longitude from the postcodes. I executed this code:

```
import postcodes_io_api
import pandas as pd
import folium

df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\AUDIO-VISUAL\Desktop\MapPinpoint\RadioFibreSites.csv', 
                 encoding='ISO-8859-1')

api = postcodes_io_api.Api(debug_http=True)

for x in df["Postcode"]:
    data = api.get_postcode(x)
    latitude = [data["result"]["latitude"]]
    longitde = [data["result"]["longitude"]]

    m = folium.Map(location=[57.240618, -2.449411],
                  zoom_start = 12,
                  tiles='Stamen Terrain')

    for la, lon in zip([data["result"]["latitude"]], [data["result"]["longitude"]]):
        folium.Marker([la, lon], popup='<i>Mt. Hood Meadows</i>').add_to(m)
```

However the `folium` map only displays the last item in the file, instead of all of them at once.

Comment: use `print()` to see what you have in variables and which part of code is executed.

Comment: did you set correct indentations in this code? It can change everything and you can create many times new map and finally get new map with only last value.

Answer (score 0):

I can't run it so I will guess.

All problem is that you create `Map` inside loop and for every `postcode` you create new map, and you put one marker, and in next loop you create new map without previous marker.

You have to create map only once - before loop.

```
import postcodes_io_api
import pandas as pd
import folium

df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\AUDIO-VISUAL\Desktop\MapPinpoint\RadioFibreSites.csv', encoding='ISO-8859-1')

api = postcodes_io_api.Api(debug_http=True)

# create map only once
m = folium.Map(location=[57.240618, -2.449411], 
                 zoom_start = 12,
                  tiles='Stamen Terrain')

# convert post and add to map
for postcode in df["Postcode"]:
    data = api.get_postcode(postcode)

    latitude = [data["result"]["latitude"]]
    longitde = [data["result"]["longitude"]]

    for la, lon in zip(latitude, longitde):
        folium.Marker([la, lon], popup='<i>Mt. Hood Meadows</i>').add_to(m)

# probably display map in Jupyter or IPython
m
```

---

**BTW:** I don't know why you put data in `[ ]` and later you use `zip()` - probably this could work

```
# convert post and add to map
for postcode in df["Postcode"]:
    data = api.get_postcode(postcode)

    lat = data["result"]["latitude"]
    lon = data["result"]["longitude"]

    folium.Marker([la, lon], popup='<i>Mt. Hood Meadows</i>').add_to(m)
```